# Display modules only on Menu item but not on the item(article) page in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I am working on a site and i want to show some modules only on the menu page but not on the child article of that menu item in joomla. Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension to gain much more control of where your modules show, and can even set it based on url... [LINK](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/10307)

Comment: i know about this module and i am looking for a open source solution, plz suggest some open source solution.

Comment: The component is open source. You do not have to purchase a license for it.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to administrator > Extention > Module > click on the menu you want to edit. Then you will have a Menu Assignment tab inside that module. Then select the "only on the pages selected" in that dropdown. And you will have all the menu item below. Just select or deselect where you want to show that item. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArA7u.png)